# pyspark: drop duplicates by great than a value

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame below:

[image]

I want to show rows based on process and station as below

[image]

Comment: Can you add more details what you mean by `great than a value`?

Comment: values in station: ab =1, xy =2, op=3, ac=4;

if process is ab will list all station (1, 2, 3, 4); process is xy =2 then list stations (2, 3, 4) ; process is op =3 then list station (3, 4), if process is ac=4 then list station (4) only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with **`split`** and **get the code value** then use `expr` to filter the records.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+------+-------+-------+--------+
#|  code|process|station|sequence|
#+------+-------+-------+--------+
#|CODE-1|     ab|     ab|       1|
#|CODE-1|     ab|     xy|       2|
#|CODE-1|     ab|     op|       3|
#|CODE-1|     ab|     ac|       4|
#|CODE-2|     xy|     ab|       1|
#|CODE-2|     xy|     xy|       2|
#|CODE-2|     xy|     op|       3|
#|CODE-2|     xy|     ac|       4|
#|CODE-3|     op|     ab|       1|
#|CODE-3|     op|     xy|       2|
#|CODE-3|     op|     op|       3|
#|CODE-3|     op|     ac|       4|
#|CODE-4|     ac|     ab|       1|
#|CODE-4|     ac|     xy|       2|
#|CODE-4|     ac|     op|       3|
#|CODE-4|     ac|     ac|       4|
#+------+-------+-------+--------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("tmp",split(col("code"),"-")[1]).\
filter(expr('sequence >= tmp')).\
drop(*["tmp"]).\
show()
#+------+-------+-------+--------+
#|  code|process|station|sequence|
#+------+-------+-------+--------+
#|CODE-1|     ab|     ab|       1|
#|CODE-1|     ab|     xy|       2|
#|CODE-1|     ab|     op|       3|
#|CODE-1|     ab|     ac|       4|
#|CODE-2|     xy|     xy|       2|
#|CODE-2|     xy|     op|       3|
#|CODE-2|     xy|     ac|       4|
#|CODE-3|     op|     op|       3|
#|CODE-3|     op|     ac|       4|
#|CODE-4|     ac|     ac|       4|
#+------+-------+-------+--------+
```

**`Option-2:`**

Using **`df.replace()`** then filter using `expr`.

```
replace_dict={"ab":"1","xy":"2","op":"3","ac":"4"}

df.withColumn("tmp",col("process")).\
replace(replace_dict,subset='tmp').\
filter(expr('sequence >= tmp')).\
drop(*["tmp"]).\
show()

#+------+-------+-------+--------+
#|  code|process|station|sequence|
#+------+-------+-------+--------+
#|CODE-1|     ab|     ab|       1|
#|CODE-1|     ab|     xy|       2|
#|CODE-1|     ab|     op|       3|
#|CODE-1|     ab|     ac|       4|
#|CODE-2|     xy|     xy|       2|
#|CODE-2|     xy|     op|       3|
#|CODE-2|     xy|     ac|       4|
#|CODE-3|     op|     op|       3|
#|CODE-3|     op|     ac|       4|
#|CODE-4|     ac|     ac|       4|
#+------+-------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: sorry, we may not able to use code value, this value could be guid or something